# JavaScript function's argument becomes undefined after the first use

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, arguments

I finally came up with code, which gets jSON data from file and now I'm trying to make some functions for that. Take a look at the code:

```
var comments = [];

function printComment(comment) {

var $comment_div = "<div class='comment'><p class='comment-text'>"+comment.comment_body+"</p><img class='comment-photo' src='"+comment.comment_url+"'/><a rel='"+comment.comment_from+"' class='name' href='"+comment.comment_url+"'>"+comment.comment_user+" via <i class='fa'></i></a></div>";

$($comment_div).appendTo('#comments-content');

};

var i = 0

$(function() {

$.getJSON("js/comments.js", function(data) {

    comments = data.comments;

    for(i; i < 3; i++ ) {

        printComment(comments[i]);
        console.log(i);

    }

    setInterval(function() {

        if ( i > comments.length ) {

            i = 0;

        } else {

            i++;
            printComment(comments[i]);
        }

        console.log(i);

    }, 5000);  

});

});
```

Problem is that the globally defined function triggers in the "for" loop with no problem, but in function in setInterval console returns "comment (which is argument of function printComment) is undefined". Could you direct me or just answer what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you have the `for` loop **and** the `setInterval`? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This is to print 3 first comments and then setInterval to print the next one every 5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your `if` condition resets `i` only if `i > comments.length`, however, if `i == comments.length` (or even `i == comment.length - 1`) then your code in the `else` block will try to access items beyond the bounds of the array. I think you're looking for something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if ( i >= comments.length ) {
        i = 0;
    }

    printComment(comments[i++]);
}, 5000);
```

Although your code is very confusing. It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to get a json file with array, then print first three items of that array and then print next one every 5 secons. When they're all printed, it should print from the 1st item. Idea is to have only 3 items at once, so it will remove one element and print the next

Comment: @szamantg I don't see where you're removing the old comments, but I'm glad I could help.

Comment: It is the rest of the code, all I needed was how to do that. Thank you once again!